# How to select only one name paired to the ID in Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset in which each id is paired with more than 1 name and in some cases the name is null. I need to decouple it to select just once the ID and the most recent updated name.

| id | name | last_updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | name1 | 04/01/2022 |
| 001 | name2 | 05/01/2022 |
| 001 | NULL | 06/01/2022 |
| 002 | name3 | 04/01/2022 |
| 002 | name4 | 05/01/2022 |
| 002 | NULL | 06/01/2022 |

In this case, I need to select the distinct IDs (001, 002) and the most recent name which is not null

| id | name | last_updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | name2 | 05/01/2022 |
| 002 | name4 | 05/01/2022 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is a typical task using SQL window functions.

We rank every row based on id and order them by date column. After it, we choose only rows with the first rank

```sql
with temp as (select *,
                     rank() over (partition by id order by last_updated desc) as rank
              from test.temp
              where name is not null)
select id, name, last_updated
from temp
where rank = 1
```